# Can I use binary search as ADT for vectors?

Tags: function, vector, adt, binary-search

I know an inbuilt function as binary_search() for quickly searching a number from sorted array. I want to ask if same binary_search function is there in STL for vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. binary_search uses template and works with several data structures. See [this example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search)